# What is the meaning of "Ich wünsche jedem (...) Dresden an den Hals"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From the Berlin-based newspaper *taz*, never shy to use unusual language, comes [this fragment](http://taz.de/Kommentar-Je-suis-Charlie-Hebdo/!152463/):

> Damit wären wir bei der anderen Seite: Ich wünsche jedem islamischen Vorbeter und seinem Nachbeter, der der Verurteilung des Mordes ein „Aber“ hinterherschiebt, lebenslang Dresden an den Hals.

The author wishes those islamists *Dresden an den Hals*.  From context, that is clearly something undesirable.  Literally it means Dresden at the throat.  But what does it mean really?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He uses *Dresden* as *Pest* is used in:

> jemandem die Pest an den Hals wünschen

which means to *curse somebody*, because Pegida is a Dresdner-born islamophobic movement. And because these 'wishes' are directed to those who dare justifying the Charlie Hebdo attack with an "aber", that make sense.

It's just a firm, if somehow hilarious, way to condemn assassination – unconditionally.

Comment: after reading the linked article I understood your answer. Do you think you can write more details to "catch" future reader by "puzzling" the facts / relevant points together without using metaphoric description? I don't wanna copy your answer just for that. My "linguistic knowledge" is that an "aber" usually negates the previous statement.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Why not? All answers here are quite incomplete. As the writers seem to have low interest in explanation, go ahead, add your aspects in your own answer.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I don't see dichotomy leading to you copying an answer if I don't complete mine. Why don't just adding a new answer completely of yours?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm If you decide to write your own A, be sure to also include the really ugly sides of "Dresden". not really grouping the Yücel-article really in the kind and friendly camp, but explicating local realities, alluded to, culminating in the not so isolated case of [Marwa al-Sherbini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Marwa_El-Sherbini), which is just one example, but an important one.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose the TAZ is referring to the PEGIDA (<sup>1</sup>), which are espcially successful in Dresden.

---

(<sup>1</sup>) "Patriotische Europäer gegen die Islamisierung des Abendlandes" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEGIDA))

Answer (score 3):

In the sentence

> *Ich wünsche ihm lebenslang Dresden an den Hals.*

the name *Dresden* is used in analogy to a punishment or similar bad thing.

Furthermore, the analogy is based on a contamination or blending of two expressions:

**1)**

> *lebenslang Dresden*
>   *lebenslang Gefängnis* (life imprisonment)

**2)**

> *Ich wünsche ihm Dresden an den Hals.*
>   *Ich wünsche ihm die Pest an den Hals.* (*jemandem die Pest an den Hals wünschen* is an idiomatic expression for ‘to curse somebody’)

Thus

> *lebenslang Dresden* + *Ich wünsche ihm Dresden an den Hals.*
>   → *Ich wünsche ihm lebenslang Dresden an den Hals.*

Answer (score 1):

There is an even darker possible interpretation of "Dresden" as a bad thing to happen to someone - the allied bombing raids on Dresden in WW2 and the resulting catastrophe. Someone not aware of the Dresden-Pegida context would not unlikely assume that interpretation.

Comment: My thoughts, also. `Dresden` is ambigous.

Comment: But the article mentions repetitively Pegida. The paragraph cannot be (unambiguously) analyzed outside that context.

Comment: Not even every German would associate Pegida with Dresden - especially those that merely consider Pegida a very ephemeral organisation that does not matter.